# How was the Google Books' Popular passages feature developed?

Tags: text-processing, pattern-recognition, corpus, n-gram, plagiarism-detection

I'm curious if anyone understands, knows or can point me to comprehensive literature or source code on how Google created their popular passage blocks feature. However, if you know of any other application that can do the same please post your answer too.

If you do not know what I am writing about [here is a link to an example](http://books.google.com/books?id=zYaK9uOxvDEC&dq=information+technology+and+law&source=gbs_navlinks_s) of Popular Passages. When you look at the overview of the book **Modelling the legal decision process for information technology applications ... By Georgios N. Yannopoulos** you can see something like:

> **Popular passages**
>
> ... direction, indeterminate. We have
>   not settled, because we have not
>   anticipated, the question which will
>   be raised by the unenvisaged case when
>   it occurs; whether some degree of
>   peace in the park is to be sacrificed
>   to, or defended against, those
>   children whose pleasure or interest it
>   is to use these things. When the
>   unenvisaged case does arise, we
>   confront the issues at stake and can
>   then settle the question by choosing
>   between the competing interests in the
>   way which best satisfies us. In
>   doing...‎ [Page 86](http://books.google.com/books?id=zYaK9uOxvDEC&pg=PA86&vq=%22When+the+unenvisaged+case+does+arise,+we+confront+the+issues+at+stake+and+can+then+settle+the+question+by+choosing%22&source=gbs_quotes_r&cad=5)
>
> [Appears in 15 books from 1968-2003](http://books.google.com/books?id=zYaK9uOxvDEC&qtid=577e7849&dq=information+technology+and+law&source=gbs_quotes_r&cad=5)
>
> This would be a world fit for
>   "mechanical" jurisprudence. Plainly
>   this world is not our world; human
>   legislators can have no such knowledge
>   of all the possible combinations of
>   circumstances which the future may
>   bring. This inability to anticipate
>   brings with it a relative
>   indeterminacy of aim. When we are bold
>   enough to frame some general rule of
>   conduct (eg, a rule that no vehicle
>   may be taken into the park), the
>   language used in this context fixes
>   necessary conditions which anything
>   must satisfy...‎  [Page 86](http://books.google.com/books?id=zYaK9uOxvDEC&pg=PA86&vq=%22Plainly+this+world+is+not+our+world%3B+human+legislators+can+have+no+such+knowledge+of+all+the+possible+combinations+of%22&source=gbs_quotes_r&cad=5)
>
> [Appears in 8 books from 1968-2000](http://books.google.com/books?id=zYaK9uOxvDEC&qtid=807e7848&dq=information+technology+and+law&source=gbs_quotes_r&cad=5)
>
> [more](http://#)

It must be an intensive pattern matching process. I can only think of n-gram models, text corpus, automatic plagisrism detection. But, sometimes n-grams are probabilistic models for predicting the next item in a sequence and text corpus (to my knowledge) are manually created. And, in this particular case, popular passages, there can be a great deal of words.

I am really lost. If I wanted to create such a feature, how or where should I start? Also, include in your response what programming languages are best suited for this stuff: F# or any other functional lang, PERL, Python, Java... (I am becoming a F# fan myself)

PS: can someone include the tag automatic-plagiarism-detection, because i can't

Comment: I tried adding the tag, but it looks like SO tags are limited to 25 characters.

Comment: *automatic-plagiarism-detection* as a tag, seems esoteric. I doubt anyone would be using as a search criteria. You may want to come up with something more generalized.

Comment: Well, that is how i've seen the industry tagging the stuff. I do not think i have the authority to change it. Go ahead and try a search and you will find some results at: ieee.org and acm.org and the MOSS project at stanford, just to name a few.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [this ACM paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1379092.1379117) by Kolak and Schilit, the Google researchers who developed Popular Passages. There are also [a few relevant slides](http://www.slideshare.net/mattlease/lecture-6-dataintensive-computing-for-text-analysis-fall-2011/62) from this MapReduce course taught by Baldridge and Lease at The University of Texas at Austin.

Answer (score 0):

In the small sample I looked over, it looks like all the passages picked were inline or block quotes. Just a guess, but perhaps Google Books looks for quote marks/differences in formatting and a citation, then uses a parsed version of the bibliography to associate the quote with the source. Hooray for style manuals.

This approach is obviously of no help to detect plagiarism, and is of little help if the corpus isn't in a format that preserves text formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which books are citing or referencing other books you don't need to look at all possible books only the books that are citing each other. If is is scientific reference often line and page numbers are included with the quote or can be found in the bibliography at the end of the book, so maybe google parses only this informations?

Google scholar certainly has the information about citing from paper to paper maybe from book to book too.